# First VBA code... looking for feedback to make it faster

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a small VBA macro to compare two worksheets and put unique values onto a new 3rd worksheet.
The code works, but every time I use if excel goes "not responding" and after 30-45sec comes back and everything worked as it should.

Can I make this faster and get rid of the "not responding" issue? is it just my computer not being fast enough?

I start with about 2500-2700 rows in each sheet I'm comparing.

```
Sub FilterNew()
Dim LastRow, x As Long

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "New"     'Adds a new Sheet to store unique values
Sheets(1).Rows("1:1").Copy Sheets("New").Rows("1:1")     'Copies the header row to the new sheet
Sheets(1).Select
LastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Cell In Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    x = 2      'This is for looking through rows of sheet2
    Dim unique As Boolean: unique = True

    Do
        If Cell.Value = Sheets(2).Cells(x, "B").Value Then   'Test if cell matches any cell on Sheet2
            unique = False     'If the cells match, then its not unique
            Exit Do            'And no need to continue testing
        End If
        x = x + 1

    Loop Until IsEmpty(Sheets(2).Cells(x, "B"))

    If unique = True Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("New").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Aside performance issues you are referring to, it is refreshing to see people documenting their code. Well done!!!

Comment: Maybe if you use a temp var to store the values, and paste the new values all at once, instead of `select the row, copy the row, paste the row` in every loop  cycle

Comment: If your code works as intended and you're looking for feedback on [any/all aspects of the code, including] performance, [codereview.se] is where you want to post it. **Make sure you STATE THE PURPOSE OF THE CODE in the title**, and describe what the code does.

Comment: FWIW "Not responding" simply means Excel is busy running your code. Nothing to worry about. Excel/VBA runs on a single thread, so while it's busy running your loops it's not going to be able to respond to user input - that's normal and expected. A good peer review will definitely make it complete faster though, but that's a bit *too broad* for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs in Code Review, but here is a link

http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

With your code your main issues are:

Selecting/Activating Sheets

Copy & pasting.

Fix those things and youll be set straight my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of a `do...loop` to find out duplicate, I would use range.find method:

```
set r = SHeets(2).range("b:b").find cell.value
if r is nothing then unique = true else unique = false
```

(quickly written and untested)

Answer (score 0):

What about this (it's should help):

```
Sub FilterNew()
Dim Cel, Rng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "New"     'Adds a new Sheet to store unique values
Sheets(1).Rows("1:1").Copy Sheets("New").Rows("1:1")     'Copies the header row to the new sheet

Set Rng = Sheet(1).Range("B2:B" & Sheet(1).Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row)

For Each Cel In Rng
    If Cel.Value <> Sheet(2).Cells(Cel.Row, 2).Value Then Cel.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("New").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) ' The only issue I have with this is that this doesn't actually tell you if the value is unique, it just tells you ins not on the same rows of the first and second sheet - Is this alright with you?
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```